# install4j 7 - handleQuit() in Mac OSX not getting called anymore

Tags: java, install4j

We recently updated our install4j version to 7 (7.0.1), we deliver our application to all platforms, including Mac OSX.

On Mac OSX, we respond to the menu that shows up at the top of the desktop by registering wtih com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener.  When a user chooses to quit an application through this menu, we get a call to our handleQuit() method.

With the recent upgrade to install4j 7 (and 7.0.1), we are no longer receiving the call to handleQuit(). As a result, I am not able to quit my application on OS X.

This used to work correctly prior to install4j 7. Is this a known issue in install4j 7 and is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

With install4j 7, you cannot use the deprecated `Application.getApplication().addApplicationListener()` in the macOS EAWT API anymore, you have to use the new API methods:

```
Application.getApplication().setQuitHandler((quitEvent, quitResponse) -> {
        quitResponse.cancelQuit();
// TODO add your code
});
```